# Extract future timeseries data and join on past timeseries that are 12 hours apart?

Tags: python, pandas, slice, data-science

I am in a data science course and my instructor isn't very strong in python.

Use a shift function to pull prices by 12 hours (aligning prices 12 hours in the future with a row's current prices). Then create a new column populated with this info.

So I should have my index, column 1, and newcolumn

I have tried a few different ways. I have tried extracting the 12 hours into a list and merging, I have tried using .slice, and I have tried creating a function.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dus3.jpg

Comment: Can you please show some (made up) sample input together with the expected output?

Comment: created_at          currency_price
12/18/2017 21:00 19.04044922
12/18/2017 22:00 19.02063314
12/18/2017 23:00 19.0287666
12/19/2017 0:00 18.99159163
12/19/2017 1:00 18.5989502
12/19/2017 2:00 18.22908317
12/19/2017 3:00 18.2000249

Comment: please [edit] your question.

Comment: Sorry still learning how to use the platform. I don't know how to show this as a table

Comment: is it possible to [edit] (click on the link) your question. You can use code formatting instead (so you enter the data, select it, and click on the code formatting button).

Comment: I attached a photo

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to work

```
slice= currency [currency.index.min():currency.index.max()]

#Move the datetime values forward an hour
shifted = slice.shift(periods=1, freq='12H')
```